# How to detect when a UIView has changed size?

Tags: iphone, debugging, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` that is initialised with a correct frame, however somewhere in my code the frame gets mangled and I'm having difficulty finding out where.

In situations like this it is usually handy to `watch` a variable in the debugger, however I have no way of accessing the controller->view->frame property in my variable view, since it isn't a variable, it's a property (surprisingly enough)

Drilling into the UIView in the variables display shows a few things but nothing I can relate to the frame, I thought perhaps that would be in `layer` but it isn't.

Is there any way to watch for changes in a private API?  I guess not, since the variables are essentially 'hidden' and so you can't specify exactly what to `watch`.

Alternatively, what other approach could I use?  I already tried subclassing UIView, setting my UIViewController's view to point to this subclass and breaking on the setFrame method but it didn't seem to work.

EDIT: the subclassing UIView method DID work, I just had to set the view to point to my test subclass in `viewDidLoad` and not the `init` method.  Leaving this question open as I'm not sure if this is the best way of approaching this kind of problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered this can be done using key value observers.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html

Comment: Were you only watching for `contentSize` or was there another property you used?

Answer (score 6):

Subclass your the view you want to track and rewrite the setFrame method:

```
@implementation MyTableView

- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame;
{
    NSLog(@"%@", frame);
    [super setFrame:frame];
}

@end
```

Then use the debugger to add a breakpoint to it and check when it gets called. Eventually, you'll see when the frame gets changed and where does the change comes from.

Comment: Sam, it should work. If the frame is changed this method should be called. If it's not maybe the problem is somewhere else upstream.

Comment: This may not get called when using auto-layout constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an ivar, view2, and just assigned it to your view in your `loadView` method. That should enable you to watch it like a normal variable.